# Цикл php данной страницы

Tags: php, get

Подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить `class` если `$_GET['page'] = $i`?
Есть php код, который выведет 5 раз данный html код

```
<li class='page-item ".$active."'><a class='page-link ".$active."' href='? 
    page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>
```

Как сделать так если `$_GET['page'] = $i` добавится переменная $active в html код. Т.е если ?page=5 переменная $active должно быть только в 5 ссылке.

```
<?php    
$pages = 100 / 20;
$active = "active";
for ( $i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++ ) 
{
echo "<li class='page-item ".$page."'><a class='page-link ".$page."' href='? 
page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

а в чем проблема? вот примерно так, как вы написали:

```
<?php
    $pages = 120 / 20;
    $active = "";

    for ( $i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++ )
    {
        $active = ($_GET['page']==$i)?"active":"";
        echo "<li class='page-item ".$page.$active."'><a class='page-link ".$page."' href='?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";
    }
?>
```